# CountingElements solution

Tags: algorithm, counting, compare-and-swap

I am trying to understand a problem and the solution provided. But not able to grasp it completely
https://codility.com/media/train/2-CountingElements.pdf

> You are given an integer m (1 <= m <= 1 000 000) and two non-empty, zero-indexed
>   arrays A and B of n integers, a0, a1, . . . , an−1 and b0, b1, . . . , bn−1 respectively (0 <= ai
>   , bi <= m).
>   The goal is to check whether there is a swap operation which can be performed on these
>       arrays in such a way that the sum of elements in array A equals the sum of elements in
>       array B after the swap. By swap operation we mean picking one element from array A and
>       one element from array B and exchanging them.

And Solution goes like this

```
def fast_solution(A, B, m):
 n = len(A)
 sum_a = sum(A)
 sum_b = sum(B)
 d = sum_b - sum_a
 if d % 2 == 1:
 return False
 d //= 2
 count = counting(A, m)
  for i in xrange(n):
  if 0 <= B[i] - d and B[i] - d <= m and count[B[i] - d] > 0:
  return True
  return False
```

(0 <= ai
, bi <= m) Does this mean (0<=ai<=bi<=m)? Is it how this equation is represented? I think this should be the case given the solution.

what is the logic behind this section?

```
 if d % 2 == 1:
 return False
 d //= 2
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the question? Just what "(0 <= ai , bi <= m)" is supposed to mean? Is the code your solution, or the actual solution, and does it work or not? Also, please fix the indentation and show some example input and output.

Comment: @tobias_k That and also if d%2==1 return false d//=2 doing

Comment: If the difference is uneven there is no way to swap such tagt the sums are the same. In the even case you know how much "mass" you need to transfer.

Comment: @SaiBot  , Thanks . Do you have any example so that I can picturize  it. Any formal proof kind of thing? And there is also division by 2.

Comment: @Sameer Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the logic behind this section?
>
> if d % 2 == 1:  return False  d //= 2

The logic is very simple.

**Explanation**

This can easily be done by following simple few steps:

```
Sum 1 = sum of (a0, a1, . . . , an−1)
```

time taken **O(N)**

```
Sum 2 = sum of (b0, b1, . . . , bn−1)
```

time taken **O(N)**

Suppose the solution pair is `(ai,bi)`. This means that: `Sum 2 + ai - bi = Sum 1 + bi - ai`, Which means that:

```
ai - bi = (Sum 1 - Sum 2)/2  // equation 1
```

The above equation indicates that **the difference of sums must be divisible by 2 for solution to exist as the arrays are made of integers**.

Looks like we can use **[binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)** . Now sort one of the arrays(say `A`) to prepare it for binary search. Time taken **O(NlogN)**. Now traverse the array B and for each `bi`, the value of `ai` can be found from above equation. So compute `ai` and check if it exist in array A using binary search. This will also take **O(NlogN)**, since we apply binary search at most **N** times in worst case.

**Alternate solution**

Another solution could be making use of [**hash table**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure which takes **O(N)** time but the space complexity would be **O(N)** .

Comment: It just means that minimum value is both arrays is 0 and maximum value in both arrays is m.

Comment: @Sameer But it does not comment anything related to ai and bi.